# How to add mean value line to plot of a factor?

Tags: r, bar-chart, mean

I have a problem with documentation and the return value of `plot()` for factors. I'd like to add a horizontal line with the mean value to the plot, but I fail to compute it. I was hoping to be able to use the value of the plot, but I failed. For example:

```
> x<-sample(5, 10, replace=TRUE)
> x
 [1] 3 5 1 4 5 4 2 4 1 5
> y<-plot(factor(x))
> y
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
```

[image: Output of plot command]
Obviously the domain and range are all integer, so what do this numbers returned by plot really mean, and how could I get the mean bar height?

Of course (if there's not a  more elegant solution) I can iterate over the factor levels counting the the number of items for each, and then take the mean value of those. Also, if you use `hist()` instead of `plot()`, then the solution is very simple: `abline(h=mean(hist(x)$counts))`

Comment: @Marco Sandri: Did you try? I feel this is wrong. I don't want the mean value of `x`, but the mean bar height.

Comment: This command plots an horizontal line at the mean bar height `abline(h=length(x)/length(y))`

Comment: @Marco Sandi: So the mean value does not depend on the values of `x` and only on the number of bars? Can you explain the mathematics behind? I also think proposed solutions should be presented in the "Answers" section...

Comment: In a past comment you wrote that you want a line at the "*mean bar height*". My solution is just what you asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably the (most?) complicated solution invented by myself is this:

```
abline(h=mean(unlist(lapply(min(x):max(x), function(ff) length(which(x == ff))))))
```

Of course this solution only works if `x` is a factor, and the levels are numeric; otherwise replace `min(x):max(x)` with `levels(x)`.

And (harder to understand for me) a more simple solution seems to be (from @Marco Sandri):

```
abline(h=length(x)/length(y))
```

Answer (score -1):

To add a horizontal line, just say:

```
    abline(h = mean(x))
```

abline(h = whatever) gives you a horizontal line. abline(y = whatever) gives you a vertical line.

Comment: You miss the point that the bars' heights are not the values of `x`, but the number of occurrences of a specific value of `x`, meaning I don't plot `x`, but `factor(x)`.

Comment: Given that `mean(x)` equals `3.4` for the example given, it's obvious that it cannot be the mean bar height, because all bars are lower than that.